# Should blog.serverfault.com be combined with the main blog

Tags: discussion, blog

At present, all of the sites share a common blog (accessible via [blog.stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/) or [blog.stackexchange.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com/), or following the link in the footer of the SO/SU/meta/careers/apps/area51) except for SF.

Surely, since the SF blog is a form of meta, discussing the infrastucture and admin behind the sites, it would sit well with the main, common blog, which discusses things such as how the software is implemented, who works to produce the sites and what changes are being made or being planned, which are also similar forms of meta.

I'm not suggesting that the two need to be combined because of a lack of content, and I'm curious as to the "exciting new announcements" mentioned by Jeff in his answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54654/is-blog-serverfault-com-still-active). Obviously if these announcements mean that the subject of the SF blog will change direction to cover SysAdmin stuff en general, and not focus on the specifics applied to our sites, then there is little reason to merge it, and doing so would bloat the main blog, but I don't think that we need to be concerned about SO users not wanting to read SF-type articles on the main blog. The main blog at present is not for SO or SU or SE users - it's mostly for people interested in the meta behind all these sites.

Comment: I'd rather see each site have their own blog...

Answer (score 3):

> Obviously if these announcements mean
>   that the subject of the SF blog will
>   change direction to cover SysAdmin
>   stuff en general, and not focus on the
>   specifics applied to our sites, then
>   there is little reason to merge it,
>   and doing so would bloat the main
>   blog, but I don't think that we need
>   to be concerned about SO users not
>   wanting to read SF-type articles on
>   the main blog.

The [first post](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/747186396/serverfault-trees) I have written actually isn't about Stack Overflow's environment and is just general system administration (Wrote it on my first day, so kind of had to be general).  Although my guess is currently that it will be dominated by the building out of the Stack Overflow environment I don't want to limit it to just that. My aim is to update it enough as well that it is worth having its own dedicated blog.

Comment: Congratulations on your new position!

Comment: The ♦ surprised me because I read the SO blog this morning and didn't recall anything about new admins. I see it's been posted since then. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to links from SF to meta.SF and blog.SF, what I'd **really** like to see is links in the same place (bottom of the page) to the meta.Stackoverflow and blog.Stackoverflow so that it's easy to get to them as well.